# Coloring chapter and section and relative numbers

Tags: sectioning, color, chapters, fancyhdr

I tried to color che chapter and the section after their restiling.

I re-used two code and mixes them, but i had no positive results.

How solve this problem??

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\color{blue}}  % sets colour of chapters
\sectionfont{\color{blue}}  % sets colour of sections

% ------------------- imposta un nuovo stile per i titoli del capitolo
%Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
%\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
% ------------------- imposta un nuovo stile per i titoli del capitolo

\begin{document}

\chapter{prova}
testo di prova

\section{prova sezione}
testo di sezione

\chapter{prova2}
testo di prova 2


\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not a LaTeX specialist, but simply with \section*{\color{blue}Introduction} I get the "Introduction" in blue color. Before doing so, since Texstudio didn´t like your "\chapterfont{\color{blue}}" neither "\sectionfont{\color{blue}}", I closed them.

Comment: if i use your code the title of chapter is blue (i known your simple strategy), but the number of each chapter remains black ...

Comment: It will be reasonable to rewrite/complete your question, so the "numbering" of sections became colored (to avoid misunderstanding).

Comment: The OP is no user on TeX.SE any longer, the question is abandoned -- I voted for closing